# Will the solution NDSolveValue finds outside of the region I give it give me bogus results?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I'm using NDSolveValue to solve [Laplace's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation) for a relatively simple system. I have two rectangles, separated by a small gap, which I define using RegionDifference:

```
\[CapitalOmega] = 
  RegionDifference[
   RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {Last@simxbds, Last@simybds}], 
    Rectangle[{0, hrect1}, {lrectbd, hrect2}]], 
   Rectangle[{rrectbd, hrect1}, {Last@simxbds, hrect2}]];
```

(The rectangles are obvious in the image below; they're the white rectangles.)

I set the boundary of one rectangle to be at 10 (Volts), and the other to be at 0. Then I use NDSolveValue to find the potential in the area outside the rectangles, like so:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Vapp, 
     lrectsideBC || lrectbotBC || lrecttopBC], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., 
     rrectsideBC || rrectbotBC || rrecttopBC]}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]];
```

(the terms ending in BC are just the inequalities for defining the boundary conditions, which will become apparent in the image below.)

If I do a DensityPlot of the solution, it looks pretty good, ostensibly accurate:

[image]

However, what I really want to do is see the field lines. To do this, I just take the gradient of the solution and plot it with StreamPlot:

```
gradField = ComplexExpand[{D[sol[x, y], x], D[sol[x, y], y]}];
Show[DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large], 
 StreamPlot[gradField, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}, ImageSize -> Large]]
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

Now, this also looks pretty good, but what's worrying me is that there are field lines inside the rectangles, where NDSolveValue wasn't supposed to be solving, and those field lines look pretty crazy. Specifically, you can see where they look pretty discontinuous, at the "diamond" shape in the middle.

The field lines actually look okay in the region where NDSolveValue was supposed to work (they look like what you'd expect, and are perpendicular to the white rectangles, as they should be), but I'm still worried that whatever is causing those field lines inside the rectangles is influencing the solution in the region I actually care about.

Is this something to worry about, or just an artifact of NDSolveValue?

edit: **to be clear, I'm not asking if the solution *inside* the rectangles (i.e., outside my NDSolve region) is accurate; I'm asking if I've set up the problem incorrectly because there *is* a strange solution inside (as opposed to no solution or something more trivial).**

For example, if you look at this problem from a physical standpoint, if the two rectangles are conductors, there should be 0 field lines inside of them. I thought it may be caused by the fact that my boundary conditions only specified the values at the *edges* of the rectangles, like so:

```
lrectsideBC = (x == lrectbd && hrect1 <= y <= hrect2);
rrectsideBC = (x == rrectbd && hrect1 <= y <= hrect2);
lrectbotBC = (0 <= x <= lrectbd && y == hrect1);
lrecttopBC = (0 <= x <= lrectbd && y == hrect2);
rrectbotBC = (rrectbd <= x <= Last@simxbds && y == hrect1);
rrecttopBC = (rrectbd <= x <= Last@simxbds && y == hrect2);
```

So to be sure I tried also specifying the values inside:

```
lrectinterior = (0 <= x <= lrectbd && hrect1 <= y <= hrect2);
rrectinterior = (rrectbd <= x <= Last@simxbds && 
    hrect1 <= y <= hrect2);
```

But that didn't change the field lines.

Edit: Full code, lengthy:

```
Vapp = 10;
interfacewidth = 60;
separation = 2;
Clear[x, y];
simxbds = {0, 100};
simybds = {0, 100};
xandbds = Flatten@({x, simxbds});
yandbds = Flatten@({y, simybds});
ymidpt = (Last@simybds)/2;
hrect1 = ymidpt - interfacewidth/2.;
hrect2 = ymidpt + interfacewidth/2.;
xmidpt = (Last@simxbds)/2;
lrectbd = xmidpt - separation/2;
rrectbd = xmidpt + separation/2;
lrectsideBC = (x == lrectbd && hrect1 <= y <= hrect2);
rrectsideBC = (x == rrectbd && hrect1 <= y <= hrect2);
lrectbotBC = (0 <= x <= lrectbd && y == hrect1);
lrecttopBC = (0 <= x <= lrectbd && y == hrect2);
rrectbotBC = (rrectbd <= x <= Last@simxbds && y == hrect1);
rrecttopBC = (rrectbd <= x <= Last@simxbds && y == hrect2);

(*I don't think we need these BC's..?*)
lrectinterior = (0 <= x <= lrectbd && hrect1 <= y <= hrect2);
rrectinterior = (rrectbd <= x <= Last@simxbds && 
   hrect1 <= y <= hrect2);

\[CapitalOmega] = 
 RegionDifference[
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {Last@simxbds, Last@simybds}], 
   Rectangle[{0, hrect1}, {lrectbd, hrect2}]], 
  Rectangle[{rrectbd, hrect1}, {Last@simxbds, hrect2}]];

sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Vapp, 
    lrectsideBC || lrectbotBC || lrecttopBC(*||lrectinterior*)], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., 
    rrectsideBC || rrectbotBC || rrecttopBC(*||rrectinterior*)]}, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]];


gradField = ComplexExpand[{D[sol[x, y], x], D[sol[x, y], y]}];


Print@Show[
     DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
      Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
      PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large], 
     StreamPlot[gradField, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
      StreamStyle -> Black, ImageSize -> Large]];
```

Comment: Without going into the details of your problem, I think it would be safe to assume that you should *not* trust the solutions of `NDSolve` outside the integration domain for which they were calculated.

Comment: @MarcoB thanks for the reply, but I'm actually still asking about the solution of NDSolve *inside* the region I solved for. I'm just asking if somehow what seems like weird behavior inside the regions means I'm doing something wrong and my solution in my solved region is skewed. I'll edit my post to make that clearer.

Comment: I would be good if you post all pieces of code to be able to reproduce this.

Comment: @user21 thanks, I think I've added the necessary code.

Comment: `Vapp` is missing.

Comment: What version of Mathematica do you have? I can not reproduce this in version 10.4.1. You might want to update, if possible.

Comment: @user21, good point, thanks. I am using version 10.3.1. Which part won't reproduce for you?

Answer (score 2):

NDSolve returned interpolation functions which come from the FEM will evaluate to `Indeterminate` if queried outiside of the region. In this case, for example:

```
RegionMember[\[CapitalOmega], {10, 50}]
(*False*)

sol[10, 50]
(*InterpolatingFunction::dmval: "Input value {10.,50.} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used."*)
(*Indeterminate*)
```

So, no, the interpolation will not give bogus results outside the region, it will give `Indeterminate`. To change that and for more info on that see the [FEM usage tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html) in the 'Extrapolation of Solution Domains' section.

Concerning the the stream lines, I can not reproduce the issue you mention; it seems to me that this works fine (I use version 10.4.1)

[image]

(As a side note, you might want to refine the mesh a bit)

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, this doesn't really answer the question I was asking.

Comment: Your question was: "Will the solution NDSolveValue finds outside of the region I give it give me bogus results?" and the answer is: No. If you have another question you need to clarify that.